# How can I run task every 10 minutes on the 5s, using BlockingScheduler?

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to run a task every 10 minutes, on the 5's, for example, at 13:15, 13:25, ....

However, it is not working.

This is only running once an hour, at the beginning of the hour, from 12 to 4pm.

`sched.add_job(run_batch, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='12-16', minute='5,15,25,35,45,55', timezone='America/Chicago')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question title indicates that you are using the *BlockingScheduler* function of the Python library -- Advanced Python Scheduler ([APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)).

Based on your question, you want to run a cron job within a Python script Monday through Friday between 1200 and 1600. You want the job to run at 12:05, 12:15, 12:25, etc.

I have not fully tested the answer below, but I did run the test for 1 hour (starting at 8am today) and it fired correctly at 8:05, 8:15, 8:25, 8:35, 8:45, 8:55 and 9:05.

I used the *start_date* variable to start the scheduler at a precise date and time.

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

# BlockingScheduler: use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

# Define the function that is to be executed
# at a scheduled time
def job_function():
    print(datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M'))

# Schedules the job_function to be executed Monday through Friday at between 12-16 at specific times.   
scheduler.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='12-16', minute='5,15,25,35,45,55', start_date='2021-03-23 12:00:00', timezone='America/Chicago')

# Start the scheduler
scheduler.start()
```

BTW You can replace these time intervals.

```
minute='5,15,25,35,45,55'
```

with this, which I tested.

```
minute='5-55/10'
```

Just a side question.  Have you considered using UTC over Central Time?

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

# BlockingScheduler: use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

# Define the function that is to be executed
# at a scheduled time
def job_function():
    print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M'))

# Schedules the job_function to be executed Monday through Friday at between 12-16 at specific times.   
scheduler.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='17-21', minute='5-55/10', start_date='2021-03-23 12:00:00', timezone='UTC')

# Start the scheduler
scheduler.start()
```

***Please let me know if you have any issues with this code and I will look into them for you.***

Comment: @CodyBugstein I always find coding fascinating, because an unknown can throw anything into chaos and questionability.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code the only problem that your system time zone is different which makes the code run when the time matches or only once. So, to solve this problem, you need to use `os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Chicago'` and it works fine. I have tested for two hours and it works for both hours on `5,15,25,35,45,55`.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import pytz
import os, time

os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Chicago'
def run_batch():
    print("Hello World")
  

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(run_batch, 'cron' ,day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='12-16', minute='5,15,25,35,45,55', timezone='America/Chicago')
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Why would the timezone matter? It would still run every five minutes regardless of the timezone

Comment: I have tried the code with and without.  I think that the code run normally first time depending on the time zone. However, if the time zone is different, the time will be different which may be out of the range of your time.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the code to run mon-fri and hours 12-16, you will need to set an interval of 10 minutes starting at 12:05. Using cron's string formatting, the code will run starting at 5 minutes and then increase by 10 each time.

```
sched.add_job(run_batch, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='12-16', minute='5-59/10', timezone='America/Chicago')
```

Comment: `minute=10` makes it run every 10 minutes ?

Comment: I don't see that in the documentation anywhere. Do you have a source?

Comment: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron

Comment: Updated the answer, as I made a typo

Comment: Are you sure it's `start` and not `start_date`?

Comment: Yes it is start_date

Comment: This didn't work, only ran on the `5`s (i.e. it didn't run at 4:15, or 8:45 etc)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by running on the 5s?

Comment: It's running at `12:05`, `13:05`, etc

Comment: Ok so every hour starting at 12:05 in the timeframe

Comment: Yes, but not every ten minutes, which is what I'm trying to do